# Can't run on android emulator which build from Corona SDK

Tags: android-emulator, coronasdk

I'm trying to run a simple code like helloworld build from Corona. It runs fine on both Corona simulator and my phone(HTC Desire HD). But when I install to Android emulator with adb and run it , it shows  an error message no matter whether I used SDK 2.3 , 3.0 , 4.0 , 4.1.2.

The message on screen is

> Unfortunately , HelloWorld has stopped"

How can I fix this problem?

There is the log:

```
     I/ActivityManager(   79): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity} from pid 512

     W/WindowManager(   79): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005

     I/WindowManager(   79): createSurface Window{41695d48 Starting com.test.hello paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)

     I/ActivityManager(   79): Start proc com.test.hello for activity com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity: pid=602 uid=10040 gids={3003}

     W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   79): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2

     I/ActivityThread(  602): Pub com.test.hello.files: com.ansca.corona.FileContentProvider

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/liblua.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/liblua.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/liblua.so 0x413436f0, skipping init

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libjnlua5.1.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libjnlua5.1.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libjnlua5.1.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Shared lib '/data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libjnlua5.1.so' already loaded in same CL 0x413436f0

     I/dalvikvm(  602): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libjnlua5.1.so)

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libopenal.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libopenal.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libmpg123.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libmpg123.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libmpg123.so 0x413436f0, skipping init

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libvorbisidec.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libvorbisidec.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libvorbisidec.so 0x413436f0, skipping init

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libalmixer.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libalmixer.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libalmixer.so 0x413436f0, skipping init

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libcorona.so 0x413436f0

     D/dalvikvm(  602): Added shared lib /data/data/com.test.hello/lib/libcorona.so 0x413436f0

     I/WindowManager(   79): createSurface Window{41693f10 com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING

     I/WindowManager(   79): createSurface Window{4150cdb8 SurfaceView paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING

     D/libEGL  (  602): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.

     D/libEGL  (  602): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so

     W/dalvikvm(  602): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)

     E/AndroidRuntime(  602): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 84

     E/AndroidRuntime(  602): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

     E/AndroidRuntime(  602):   at android.opengl.derived.SwapGLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(SwapGLSurfaceView.java:500)

     E/AndroidRuntime(  602):   at android.opengl.derived.SwapGLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(SwapGLSurfaceView.java:658)

     E/AndroidRuntime(  602):   at android.opengl.derived.SwapGLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(SwapGLSurfaceView.java:884)

     E/AndroidRuntime(  602):   at android.opengl.derived.SwapGLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(SwapGLSurfaceView.java:825)

     D/gralloc_goldfish(  602): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

     W/ActivityManager(   79):   Force finishing activity com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity

     W/WindowManager(   79): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21020

     W/InputManagerService(   79): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415fe078 (uid=10040 pid=602)

     W/InputManagerService(   79): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415a8278

     I/WindowManager(   79): createSurface Window{416003c0  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING

     F/libc    (  602): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

     W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   79): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2

     I/ActivityManager(   79): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity} from pid 512

     W/WindowManager(   79): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005

     I/WindowManager(   79): createSurface Window{41596490 Starting com.test.hello paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING

     W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(   79): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2

     I/DEBUG   (  597): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

     I/DEBUG   (  597): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.0.2/ICS_MR0/229537:eng/test-keys'

     I/DEBUG   (  597): pid: 602, tid: 602  >>> com.test.hello <<<

     I/DEBUG   (  597): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  r0 00000000  r1 47a23e64  r2 00000000  r3 0010d090

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  r4 47a6a498  r5 42a7cca0  r6 47a23e64  r7 42a7cca8

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  r8 beeee638  r9 42a7cca0  10 00012820  fp beeee64c

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  ip 00000000  sp beeee610  lr 4795e718  pc 4795d484  cpsr 80000010

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d0  0000032044482000  d1  0000000044482000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  000000003f000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d6  7e37e43c8800759c  d7  0000000000000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000

     I/DEBUG   (  597):  scr 60000012

     I/DEBUG   (  597): 

     I/Process (  602): Sending signal. PID: 602 SIG: 9

     I/ActivityManager(   79): Process com.test.hello (pid 602) has died.

     W/ActivityManager(   79): Force removing ActivityRecord{415a79f0 com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity}: app died, no saved state

     W/InputDispatcher(   79): channel '41693f10 com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8

     E/InputDispatcher(   79): channel '41693f10 com.test.hello/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Maybe paste your source for mor information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on GPU emulation on android emulator. I had the same problem...